What's the best way to check that my cigar box guitar works, without an amp?
I have built a cigar box guitar. The pickup is a cheap humbucker. I bought a cheap little line-out amp... This guy...
https://www.joyoaudio.co.uk/JOYO-ja-01-2w-guitar-mini-amplifier-with-9v-battery-black
Plugged it in... And nothing...
I have a multimeter, which seemed to confirm that the humbucker was fine (low resistance,) whereas the amp had high resistance. This would seem to confirm that the issue is the amp. It's just a faulty unit.
But I don't really understand this stuff. I could be wrong about what the multimeter was telling me. And I don't want to buy another amp if it's not the amp that's the problem.
I just need to confirm whether there's a signal coming from the guitar's line-out.
I went down a rabbit hole researching computer guitar interfaces, like iRig and USB guitar cables. But it would seem to me that having a digital system "reading" an analog signal would be unnecessarily complicated. I.e., the level of complexity would be such that if it still didn't work, I still couldn't be sure the issue was the humbucker.
So, what I am thinking now is connecting the guitar to my stereo speakers via a phono preamp. As I understand it, stereo speakers don't make very good guitar amplifiers because a stereo is a high-fidelity system, so you don't get the characteristic distortion that defines the electric guitar sound.
So the stereo speakers wouldn't be a long-term substitute for an amp, but wouldn't they confirm that the guitar works? If there is a signal, wouldn't they play it?
I understand from my DIY turntable that analog signals are relatively weak, that's why I need the preamp to play the turntable through my modern stereo. And I imagine an analog signal from an electric guitar would be weak in the same way. But is it? Would the phono preamp that amplifies the signal from the turntable do the same for an electric guitar?

"Low resistance" and "high resistance" don’t really mean anything in this context. You can see if the amp works without a guitar by cranking the amp and tapping the end of a cable plugged into it with you hand. If it pops when you tap, it’s working. If the amp works then you can use that to tell if the guitar works. If the amp doesn’t work, you’re gonna need a working amp sooner or later. If you never plan to use an amp, it doesn’t matter if the guitar works.

@ToddWilcox Thanks for the fantastically simple answer. And yes, I will use an amp, I just don't want to buy another one if the one I have works fine. I'm just tying to rule it in or out as the issue. I'd still like to hear some opinions about using a stereo speaker.

@ToddWilcox A guitar pickup should have reasonably low resistance (usually in the range of 5-10kΩ), else chances are high that the wire is broken at some point. A guitar amplifier on the other hand ... I would rather say if you didn’t have a high resistance between signal in and ground then something is really off ...

Along with Todd's suggestion, first thing I'd check is the lead itself. If that's faulty. you're never going to get a signal to the amp, even when you tap the jack.

I’d suggest you to test components individually:

You can test the amp by plugging a source that works into the amp (this can also be a line level source such as your phone). This way you can easily check if the amp is defective.

If the amp works fine the issue might be the guitar or the cable. If you have a spare cable you can try this. You can also use your multimeter to check that there is connection between tip to tip and ground to ground and no connection between tip and ground.

If the cable is good the issue must be the guitar. Here you can have multiple faulty components:

The pickups
The jack
The wiring

To check these you might first want to try simply measuring from the jack connector: Do you have a connection from pin to ground (the resistance should essentially be the resistance of the pickup as long as you do not have any pots in the way)? If you do not have any there is a connection issue at some point. If you have a really low resistance there is a short circuit at some point. Measure these using a cable, since the jack connector itself might be faulty.
Now you have three possible outcomes:

No connection:
There is a connection error at some point. Open the guitar and check each component in the wiring path. This might require fixing a solder point, it might also require replacing (or trying to fix) a component (such as the jack connector).

Low resistance:
There is some short circuit in the path. Open the guitar and check if there are unwanted contacts in the wiring path.

No apparent problems:
Check if the pickup works. This can be done using a multimeter: If you move something magnetic in front of the pickup you should be able to measure a voltage. If you don’t, the pickup is probably bad. If you do, check if you can measure the voltage further down the line, up to the ends of the cable.




Also check that the battery of your amp is fresh enough.

Don't you just hate it when you think you have a really complex issue, then someone comes along with a simple answer... Especially your first suggestion, I can't believe I didn't think of that. As for 3.3, that's really handy too, because I couldn't figure out how to directly test the pickups. So, where would I put the multimeter points to check this? And would a fridge magnet do, or do I need a stronger one?

@MichaelAtkins-Prescott At the leads of the pickup. I like to use the tip of a magnetic screwdriver for this ...
